# Xamarin Native Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, native

It is possible using Entity Framework in xamarin native? I want to create an Entity Framework model from a database (SQL Server). If it is possible how I can do it?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11284/entity-framework-code-first-approach-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

Not by the looks of things at the moment, because Xamarin is dependent on the cross-platform SQLite Engine which is not supported yet by EF.  See here: [Xamarin.Forms support #4269](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4269)

Comment: SQLite is the native built in database but this question most likely relates to the fact you can access internet facing databases.

Comment: Ah OK.  I hadn't thought of doing that.  For that I'd use a service layer in client app to access data exposed through a Web API.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer: Not Possible.

Reason: You should not expose connection string, queries, authentication on Client Side. Remember that different from a Webapi or MVC app, mobile app is all at client side, it is exposing your database.

Imagine like you are using entity framework on the browser. If they open the app (crackers) they will have credentials, server, they may query your database.